# Read from non-text files in C++?

Tags: c++, cad, file-read

My friend gave me a project that requires reading from a non-text file in C++. I'm creating a search and find feature where it looks through the filename of each document for that search, but yet also searches each individual file and will return any results given. To be more specific; the file types I'll be using to test it out are .dmg and .dwf. (They are both CAD files) He wants to be able to search through the text of each drawing. Is this at all possible? All I could find on google was reading from text files and binary files.

Comment: Any reason this needs to be implemented in C++? IMO Python would be 10x easier to work with for this job.

Comment: Also, do the CAD files have plain text embedded inside of them, or is the text encoded?

Comment: Not really, I'm just more familiar with C++.

Comment: I'm not entirely too sure on that. I don't have a program to open a sample file I downloaded.

Comment: Just force it open with any text editor (like Sublime) and take a look (i.e. `Open With...`).

Comment: If it's plain text (and it probably is), just open as binary and search for "text".  If he wants to find find particular strings, see grep.  If he wants to find all the text in general, see "strings".  (The only encoding it might use, is to store the text as UTF-16)

Comment: Possible, but you should do some reading on the file formats first so you know what to look for and how to interpret it. Otherwise you might find yourself looking past the strings in the file without realizing it.

Comment: Purports to be the dwg specification:  https://www.opendesign.com/files/guestdownloads/OpenDesign_Specification_for_.dwg_files.pdf

Comment: Autodesk has a c++ toolkit for working with dwf files: http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/index?id=823771&siteID=123112 are you sure the other file type is .dmg and not .[dwg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.dwg) which would make more sense as the former is a disk image format used by Apple and the latter is a format used in CAD software.

Comment: @RPGillespie It seems to be encoded. I opened it with Notepad++ and it's just a bunch of symbols.

Comment: @jpw Your correct, it is dwg; not dmg. There was a miss-spell communication error lol

Comment: Good thing it isn't dmg. The dmg from one nat-20 could ruin your whole day.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ strings myfile.dwf | grep search_for_me
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: How is this related to the question? The OP wants to write a function in C++ that will locate a file and then parse it's contents based on a CAD format.

Comment: It's pretty much any shell. I'm pointing out that, unless the problem _absolutely_ has to be written in C++, it's a _lot_ simpler in shell.